# How to set up debezium watcher in dockerfile that can perform its function in the debezium mysql tutorial

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

I'm going through the tutorial, and everything runs well when running individual containers in different terminals. https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/1.8/tutorial.html#viewing-change-events
But when combined into a
`docker-compose.yml` [file](https://github.com/debezium/debezium-examples/blob/main/tutorial/docker-compose-postgres.yaml), adding a watcher like this no longer watches correctly:

```yaml
  ...the other configs

  watcher:
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
      - kafka
    container_name: "watcher"
    image: "debezium/kafka:1.8"
    links:
      - "zookeeper:zookeer"
      - "kafka:kafka"
    command: watch-topic -a -k dbserver1.inventory.customers
```

The logs I'm getting from this are:

```
[2022-03-07 07:40:35,580] WARN [Consumer clientId=consumer-console-consumer-94982-1, groupId=console-consumer-94982] Bootstrap broker 0.0.0.0:9092 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2022-03-07 07:40:36,432] WARN [Consumer clientId=consumer-console-consumer-94982-1, groupId=console-consumer-94982] Connection to node -1 (/0.0.0.0:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2022-03-07 07:40:36,432] WARN [Consumer clientId=consumer-console-consumer-94982-1, groupId=console-consumer-94982] Bootstrap broker 0.0.0.0:9092 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2022-03-07 07:40:37,545] WARN [Consumer clientId=consumer-console-consumer-94982-1, groupId=console-consumer-94982] Connection to node -1 (/0.0.0.0:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2022-03-07 07:40:37,545] WARN [Consumer clientId=consumer-console-consumer-94982-1, groupId=console-consumer-94982] Bootstrap broker 0.0.0.0:9092 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2022-03-07 07:40:38,668] WARN [Consumer clientId=consumer-console-consumer-94982-1, groupId=console-consumer-94982] Connection to node -1 (/0.0.0.0:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2022-03-07 07:40:38,668] WARN [Consumer clientId=consumer-console-consumer-94982-1, groupId=console-consumer-94982] Bootstrap broker 0.0.0.0:9092 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2022-03-07 07:40:39,650] WARN [Consumer clientId=consumer-console-consumer-94982-1, groupId=console-consumer-94982] Connection to node -1 (/0.0.0.0:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2022-03-07 07:40:39,650] WARN [Consumer clientId=consumer-console-consumer-94982-1, groupId=console-consumer-94982] Bootstrap broker 0.0.0.0:9092 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
```

Also tried to attach to network, still no good.
What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a variable of `ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: kafka` to the broker service, or use an external client rather than another container to consume the data.

Worth pointing out that `links` is a deprecated feature of Compose, and should not be relied upon. Do use `networks`, appropriately.